# _buildSchema error in my validation of my form

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Good evening to all,
I'm trying to validate a form under cake php but I encounter the following error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of App\Form\ContactForm::_buildSchema(Cake\Form\Schema $schema) must be compatible with Cake\Form\Form::_buildSchema(Cake\Form\Schema $schema): Cake\Form\Schema in \src\Form\ContactForm.php on line 11

Here is the code of my page /src/Form/ContactForm.php :

```
namespace App\Form;

use Cake\Form\Form;
use Cake\Form\Schema;
use Cake\Mailer\Email;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class ContactForm extends Form
{
    protected function _buildSchema(Schema $schema)
    {
        return $schema->addField('message', 'text')
            ->addField('name', 'string')
            ->addField('email', ['type' => 'string'])
            ->addField('subject', ['type' => 'string']);
    }
    enter code here
    protected function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator->add('name', 'length', [
                'rule' => ['minLength', 10],
                'message' => 'A name is required' 
            ])->add('email', 'format', [
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'A valid email address is required',
            ]);

    //     return $validator;
    // }

    // protected function _execute(array $data)
    // {
    //     // Send an email.
    //     return true;
    // }
```

Do you have an idea where this can come from?

Comment: The error is a typical for cakephp 4, look here how to https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/form.html#creating-a-form and for cakephp 3 https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/form.html#creating-a-form

Comment: Like the error message says, `_buildSchema(Cake\Form\Schema $schema)` is not the same as `_buildSchema(Cake\Form\Schema $schema): Cake\Form\Schema`.